# how to resize scroll view after remove subview swift?

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview

I have subview in a scrollview and after I remove some subview from the bottom there is a blank space and the scroll view still keeps height, not resizing. How to fix this?

Comment: use stack view to avoid manual resizing

Answer (score 0):

Scrollview's `contentHeight` & `contentWidth` is calculated from its subviews(if used auto layout). If autolayout is not used then you need to set its content size.

So whenever you are adding or removing subviews in scrollview you need to take care of its contentHeight and contentWidth.

**If you're using auto layout,** you need to add constraints to newly added view in such a way that scroll view can calculate its contentHeight from it.(in auto layouts you don't need to explicitly set the content height to scroll view)

**If you're using frame base layout,** you need to set the contentHeight explicitly to the scroll view. In frame base layout, you need to take care of scrollviews content size.

**Why is there blank space in scrollview?**

When a subview is removed from scrollview, its content size need to be adjusted. It means it is not able to calculate its content size.

Comment: it's blank space of subview, which I removed from scroll view .

Comment: For that you need to set bottom constrain for scrollview. Set the constraint like last subview of scrollview's bottom to scrollview's bottom and set constant to zero.

Comment: thanks @Mahendra  , yes,I tried and there has not blank space but appear blank space of other subview above last subview.

Comment: If you remove subview between other subviews then you need to set vertical  constraint in place of removed subview.

Answer (score 0):

`UIScrollView` doesn't know the height of its content automatically. You must calculate the height and width for yourself like below:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 700)
```

note: change `width` and `height` as you want.

you can try this also:

```
let content: CGRect = scrollView.subviews.reduce(into: .zero) { rect, view in
    rect = rect.union(view.frame)
}
scrollView.contentSize = content.size
```

Comment: After removing subview from scrollview, content size need to be recalculated. You can not set static value like 700. there will be blank space at bottom of the scrollview . So the question remains same and you answer does  not fix this.

Comment: @RyanLe can you getting your last/bottom view?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this line

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: (YOURVIEW) - (THEREMOVEDVIEW))
```

I recommend you that you must save the height before remove view for later you can adjust.

Comment: It depends on how you use auto layout, the most time its works, if it doesn't work, show me how is your auto layout